# Python itertools product function in lua

Tags: lua, combinatorics

I'm looking for a way to implement a python-like combinatorics function `product` from `itetools` library, with `repeat` argument, in lua.

I found this library
https://github.com/aperezdc/lua-itertools/blob/master/itertools.lua
but not sure if this can be useful to me, because I couldn't find `product` function there

What could be an algorithm for implementing such a function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function:

```
function ProductRepeat(tab, repeatCount)
    local result = { {} }

    for _ = 1, repeatCount do
        local newResult = { }

        for _, r in ipairs(result) do
            for _, v in ipairs(tab) do
                table.insert(newResult, { v, unpack(r) })
            end
        end

        result = newResult
    end

    return result
end
```